# Continuar a execução do loop mesmo que uma passagem dê problema

Tags: r, loop, exceção

Estou baixando os dados de ações da Bovespa pelo pacote `quantmod`.

No entanto, ainda não sei o porquê, nos dados do Santander (SANB11) a função `getSymbols` do pacote está dando problema e o loop para a execução. Tem uma maneira de fazer o loop continuar a execução mesmo quando uma etapa do loop deu erro?

```
library(quantmod)    
tickers<-c("OIBR4.SA", "PCAR4.SA", "PDGR3.SA", "PETR3.SA", "PETR4.SA", "RENT3.SA", 
           "RSID3.SA", "SANB11.SA", "SBSP3.SA", "SUZB5.SA", "TIMP3.SA", 
           "TRPL4.SA", "UGPA3.SA", "USIM3.SA", "USIM5.SA", "VAGR3.SA", "VALE3.SA", 
           "VALE5.SA", "VIVT4.SA")

for (i in tickers){
getSymbols(i,src="yahoo")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a função [`try`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/try.html). Seu código ficará assim:

```r
for (i in tickers) {
  try(getSymbols(i,src="yahoo"))
}
```

A função `try` avalia a expressão passada como parâmetro e captura qualquer erro que ocorra durante a avaliação, evitando que a execução do script seja interrompida por causa do erro.

Se você precisar tratar o erro, use a função [`tryCatch`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/conditions.html).